# Why not delete all duplicates?

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLite

here data

```
   |  80 |    1536843922000 | 24440271 | 26B008D0-EDA3-4F83-9AFF-6C04BBB1BF33 |
   | 109 |    1536843922000 | 36656927 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
   |  83 |    1536843922000 | 94020805 | 26B008D0-EDA3-4F83-9AFF-6C04BBB1BF33 |

   |  77 |    1536930322000 | 22240444 | 26B008D0-EDA3-4F83-9AFF-6C04BBB1BF33 |
   |  53 |    1536930322000 | 24424792 | 26B008D0-EDA3-4F83-9AFF-6C04BBB1BF33 |
   |  79 |    1536930322000 | 24440271 | 26B008D0-EDA3-4F83-9AFF-6C04BBB1BF33 |
   | 113 |    1536930322000 | 37473218 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
   | 115 |    1536930322000 | 38483615 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
   | 116 |    1536930322000 | 38483615 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
   |  47 |    1537016722000 | 24253674 | 26B008D0-EDA3-4F83-9AFF-6C04BBB1BF33 |
   | 105 |    1537016722000 | 34664388 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
   | 117 |    1537016722000 | 38483615 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
   |  58 |    1537103122000 | 37045208 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
   |  59 |    1537103122000 | 37045208 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
```

And here sqlite query that delete duplicates:

```
DELETE FROM notification_invoice WHERE notificationDate >= 1536883200000   AND providerId in ("26B008D0-EDA3-4F83-9AFF-6C04BBB1BF33","9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4") 
     AND EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
              FROM notification_invoice t2
             WHERE t2.providerId in ("26B008D0-EDA3-4F83-9AFF-6C04BBB1BF33","9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4") 
               AND t2.notificationDate = notification_invoice.notificationDate
               AND notification_invoice.notificationDate >= 1536019200000
               AND t2.ownerKey  = notification_invoice.ownerKey 
               AND t2._id > notification_invoice._id
       )
```

And here result:

```
   | _id | notificationDate | ownerKey | providerId                           |
   |-----+------------------+----------+--------------------------------------|
   |  58 |    1537103122000 | 37045208 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
   | 115 |    1536930322000 | 38483615 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
```

No I check result by get all data:

```
select _id, notificationDate, ownerKey, providerid from notification_invoice where notificationDate >= 1536883200000 and providerId in ("26B008D0-EDA3-4F83-9AFF-6C04BBB1BF33","9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4") order by  ownerKey, notificationDate
```

here result:

```
| _id | notifDate | ownerKey | providerId                           |
|-----+------------------+----------+--------------------------------------|
|  77 |    1536930322000 | 22240444 | 26B008D0-EDA3-4F83-9AFF-6C04BBB1BF33 |
|  47 |    1537016722000 | 24253674 | 26B008D0-EDA3-4F83-9AFF-6C04BBB1BF33 |
|  53 |    1536930322000 | 24424792 | 26B008D0-EDA3-4F83-9AFF-6C04BBB1BF33 |
|  79 |    1536930322000 | 24440271 | 26B008D0-EDA3-4F83-9AFF-6C04BBB1BF33 |
| 105 |    1537016722000 | 34664388 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
|  59 |    1537103122000 | 37045208 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
| 113 |    1536930322000 | 37473218 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
| 116 |    1536930322000 | 38483615 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
| 117 |    1537016722000 | 38483615 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
```

As you case success delete all duplicate except one:

```
| 116 |    1536930322000 | 38483615 | 9856BAB6-51BE-4EA8-B0D7-72ABF4A452A4 |
```

Why not delete this record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `_id = 116` in your sample data there is only 1 `_id = 117` such as 
`t2._id > notification_invoice._id`, 
but for these 2 ids (116 and 117), this condition:

```
t2.notificationDate = notification_invoice.notificationDate
```

fails. 
So `EXIST` returns `false`.

Comment: And how I can fix. I need to delete all duplicate even when notificationDate are not equals

Comment: Remove `t2.notificationDate = notification_invoice.notificationDate` if then you still consider them to be duplicates.